# How can we express more complex logical expressions in Mathematica?

Tags: logic

How can we use quantifiers to express something a bit more complex such as - for example - the definition of limit:

$$\forall \epsilon >0\hspace{2mm} \exists \delta >0 \hspace{.5mm} :\hspace{.5mm} 0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$

It's not clear to me how to express double quantifiers and the "such that". My objective is to be able to verify negations of such expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done as follows, adding a quantifier on $x$.

```
ForAll[\[Epsilon], \[Epsilon] > 0,  Exists[\[Delta], \[Delta] > 0, 
ForAll[x, Implies[0 < RealAbs[x - a] && RealAbs[x - a] < \[Delta], 
 RealAbs[f[x] - L] < \[Epsilon]]]]]
```

For example,

```
a = 2; f[x_] := x^2; L = 4;
Resolve[ForAll[\[Epsilon], \[Epsilon] > 0, 
Exists[\[Delta], \[Delta] > 0,  ForAll[x, 
Implies[0 < RealAbs[x - a] && RealAbs[x - a] < \[Delta], 
RealAbs[f[x] - L] < \[Epsilon]]]]], Reals]
```

> `True`

If we replace `L=4;` by `L=5;`, the above results in `False`.